Determining the fundamental group of the following quotient
Let $X$ be te quotient of a hexagon identifying the sides as in the scheme $aaabbb^{-1}$. By theorem 74.2 from Munkres I know that if all vertices are identified, then
$$
\pi_1(X,x_0)\cong\frac{F(a,b)}{\langle aaabbb^{-1} \rangle _N}
$$
Where $F(a,b)$ is the free group with generators $a,b$.
This can be easily verified:

And $\langle A, B | A^3B \rangle\cong \langle A\rangle \cong\mathbb{Z}$.
Therefore $\pi_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$

You should probably start by verifying that all vertices are indeed identified. Then use your knowledge on how to manipulate group presentations. Do you know about Tietze transformations?

I have already verified that, but didn't add any picture, sorry. My knowledge on group presentations is 0, I'll check that thanks

@MoisheKohan So from $A^3B=1$ I get that $B=A^{-3}$ and therefore $\langle A, B | A^3B\rangle \cong \langle A \rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}$, right?
